# Using lambda to describe always upto-date attitude of an object

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

As part of a answer on the [code golf sister site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), I used a lambda function that returned the number of newlines present in a string, like so:

`newlines = lambda v: len([n for n in v if n=='\n'])`

This was used in a further list comprehension to constantly provide an up-to-date answer regarding a chosen string, and be used to determine which condition to test i.e. which letter to compare against, for example this hypothetical code:

`string += letter if letter in [[A, B, ... Y, Z,], '\n'][newlines(string)] else None`

My query is whether this is considered standard and an acceptable method of using lambda, or whether another method is more conventional.

Comment: Once you get into that many layers of lambda'ing and comprehensions, it's probably best for (human) comprehension if you just spell it out as for-loops.

Comment: Incidentally, I think maybe you didn't mean ["equerry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equerry).

Comment: Odd way to write `v.count("\n")`, if `v` is a list.

Comment: Yeah, forgive me for my English/French, it's not my strong suit at all (your link was amusing, through). Anyway, I see that it makes sense that readable for-loops are preferred over the above.

Comment: Rightly oh, DCM. This calls another tool to fit to my belt. Still a new programmer, you see :).